# Obtain decidable total order on a type from an injection into `nat`

Tags: module, typeclass, coq

Since the natural numbers support a decidable total order, the injection [`nat_of_ascii (a : ascii) : nat`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Strings.Ascii.html#nat_of_ascii) induces a decidable total order on the type `ascii`. What would be a concise, idiomatic way of expressing this in Coq? (With or without type classes, modules, etc.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Such process is fairly routine and will depend on the library you have chosen. For [order.v](https://github.com/math-comp/finmap/blob/master/order.v), based on math-comp, the process is totally mechanical [in fact, we'll develop a general construction for types with an injection to total orders later in the post]:

```
From Coq Require Import Ascii String ssreflect ssrfun ssrbool.
From mathcomp Require Import eqtype choice ssrnat.
Require Import order.

Import Order.Syntax.
Import Order.Theory.

Lemma ascii_of_natK : cancel nat_of_ascii ascii_of_nat.
Proof. exact: ascii_nat_embedding. Qed.

(* Declares ascii to be a member of the eq class *)
Definition ascii_eqMixin := CanEqMixin ascii_of_natK.
Canonical ascii_eqType := EqType _ ascii_eqMixin.

(* Declares ascii to be a member of the choice class *)
Definition ascii_choiceMixin := CanChoiceMixin ascii_of_natK.
Canonical ascii_choiceType := ChoiceType _ ascii_choiceMixin.

(* Specific stuff for the order library *)
Definition ascii_display : unit. Proof. exact: tt. Qed.

Open Scope order_scope.

(* We use the order from nat *)
Definition lea x y := nat_of_ascii x <= nat_of_ascii y.
Definition lta x y := ~~ (lea y x).

Lemma lea_ltNeq x y : lta x y = (x != y) && (lea x y).
Proof.
rewrite /lta /lea leNgt negbK lt_neqAle.
by rewrite (inj_eq (can_inj ascii_of_natK)).
Qed.
Lemma lea_refl : reflexive lea.
Proof. by move=> x; apply: le_refl. Qed.
Lemma lea_trans : transitive lea.
Proof. by move=> x y z; apply: le_trans. Qed.
Lemma lea_anti : antisymmetric lea.
Proof. by move=> x y /le_anti /(can_inj ascii_of_natK). Qed.
Lemma lea_total : total lea.
Proof. by move=> x y; apply: le_total. Qed.

(* We can now declare ascii to belong to the order class. We must declare its
   subclasses first. *)
Definition asciiPOrderMixin :=
  POrderMixin lea_ltNeq lea_refl lea_anti lea_trans.

Canonical asciiPOrderType  := POrderType ascii_display ascii asciiPOrderMixin.

Definition asciiLatticeMixin := Order.TotalLattice.Mixin lea_total.
Canonical asciiLatticeType := LatticeType ascii asciiLatticeMixin.
Canonical asciiOrderType := OrderType ascii lea_total.
```

Note that providing an order instance for `ascii` gives us access to a large theory of total orders, plus operators, etc..., however the definition of total itself is fairly simple:

```
"<= is total" == x <= y || y <= x
```

where <= is a "decidable relation" and we assume, of course, decidability of equality for the particular type. Concretely, for an arbitrary relation:

```
Definition total (T: Type) (r : T -> T -> bool) := forall x y, r x y || r y x.
```

so if `T` is and order, and satisfies `total`, you are done.

More generally, you can define a generic principle to build such types using injections:

```
Section InjOrder.

Context {display : unit}.
Local Notation orderType := (orderType display).
Variable (T : orderType) (U : eqType) (f : U -> T) (f_inj : injective f).

Open Scope order_scope.

Let le x y := f x <= f y.
Let lt x y := ~~ (f y <= f x).
Lemma CO_le_ltNeq x y: lt x y = (x != y) && (le x y).
Proof. by rewrite /lt /le leNgt negbK lt_neqAle (inj_eq f_inj). Qed.
Lemma CO_le_refl : reflexive le. Proof. by move=> x; apply: le_refl. Qed.
Lemma CO_le_trans : transitive le. Proof. by move=> x y z; apply: le_trans. Qed.
Lemma CO_le_anti : antisymmetric le. Proof. by move=> x y /le_anti /f_inj. Qed.

Definition InjOrderMixin : porderMixin U :=
  POrderMixin CO_le_ltNeq CO_le_refl CO_le_anti CO_le_trans.
End InjOrder.
```

Then, the `ascii` instance gets rewritten as follows:

```
Definition ascii_display : unit. Proof. exact: tt. Qed.
Definition ascii_porderMixin := InjOrderMixin (can_inj ascii_of_natK).
Canonical asciiPOrderType := POrderType ascii_display ascii ascii_porderMixin.

Lemma lea_total : @total ascii (<=%O)%O.
Proof. by move=> x y; apply: le_total. Qed.

Definition asciiLatticeMixin := Order.TotalLattice.Mixin lea_total.
Canonical asciiLatticeType := LatticeType ascii asciiLatticeMixin.
Canonical asciiOrderType := OrderType ascii lea_total.
```